# VB.NET RTB line counter?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a simple line counter for a rich text box control. Right now, I have a label to the left of the box, using this code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count()

End Sub
```

This works fine. Same as on a button, it will just update the number. The issue i'm having is using this code:

```
    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + RichTextBox1.Lines.Count() + Environment.NewLine
```

I get:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "

" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Any fix? Thanks

Comment: `RichTextBox1.Lines.Count()` returns a number, `+` is for addition, so you are trying to Add "something" + 42 + <NL>.  Use "&" for string concatenation and `.ToString` on `Count()`     Turn on Option Strict - the first block is in need also

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the way this is designed, every time you type a letter in, the label will append a new line with the line count to it.  I'm not certain if this is the intended result or not (seems a little odd to me) but you might try clearing the label's text first, if that's not what you're trying to go for. simply add `Label2.Text = ""` to clear out the text, before you assign the text to the linecount.

Comment: Thanks! Would there be any way to check for the amount of lines in the rich text box, and set the label to that many newlines? For example, each time it changes, check the lines, and instead of adding a new line (because you could just backspace a line), check for the lines and set the label to it? I'm thinking you could set a variable to the line count, and split each number up and make a new line for each one. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Label2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

The operator to concatenate strings in VB.NET is the `&` character, not the `+` character. The `RichTextBox1.Lines.Count()` returns a value of Integer type; in order to return a string representation of that value you should call the `ToString()` method.

try using this instead:

```
Label2.Text &= RichTextBox1.Lines.Count.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
```

That will append the line count value to the end of the label every time the code is executed. However if you are making a line counter that will simply report the number of lines in the RichTextBox, I would suggest using the following:

```
Label2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count.ToString()
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like,

Label2.Text = Label2.Text + System.Convert.ToString(RichTextBox1.Lines.Count()) + Environment.NewLine

Comment: Why not just do `.Count().ToString()`? Also, it is much better practise to actually use the concatenation operator (`&`) when concatenating strings rather than `+`.